# pandas keep data type when creating panel

Tags: python, pandas

If I create a DataFrame where one column is an object and the other is an integer, place that DataFrame into a dictionary and then use that dictionary to create a Panel, the integer data type disappears:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

a=['a' for i in range(1000)]
b=[i for i in range(1000)]
c = {'c':a[:], 'b':b[:]}
df = pd.DataFrame(c)

print df

d = dict()
d['x'] = df
p = pd.Panel(d)

print p['x']
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
b    1000  non-null values
c    1000  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
b    1000  non-null values
c    1000  non-null values
dtypes: object(2)
```

Is there a way of preserving the data types when creating a Panel from a DataFrame-containing dictionary?

Comment: I am fighting with this same problem, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not really :( The closest I came was setting the type again later (see my comment to one of the answers below).

Comment: I think the problem is with panel itself. (I added one possible [bad solution] as an answer below). I restructured my data and moved to dict of dataframes which is fine for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that there is no way to do this unless you change orientation.

The bug report that explains the issue is here:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/359

I quote the relevant part below:

> in the example below, "a" is a mixed type dataframe. Once included in
>   the Panel, all columns become of type object:

[..]

> Panel can only be heterogeneous in the items. I just added an orient
>   option to Panel so you can do:

```
In [4]: panel = Panel.from_dict({'1':a,'2':b}, orient='minor')

In [5]: panel
Out[5]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 30 (major) x 2 (minor)
Items: a to c
Major axis: 0 to 29
Minor axis: 1 to 2

In [6]: panel['a'].values.dtype
Out[6]: dtype('float64')

In [7]: panel['b'].values.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('object')

In [8]: panel['c'].values.dtype
Out[8]: dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

They need to be in separate frames to avoid combining types. Here is one way

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame(c)

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
b    1000  non-null values
c    1000  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)

In [54]: df['x'] = 'x'

In [55]: df['y'] = range(len(df))

In [56]: p = df.set_index(['x','y']).to_panel()

In [10]: p['b']
Out[10]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, x to x
Columns: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
dtypes: int64(1000)

In [11]: p['c']
Out[11]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1 entries, x to x
Columns: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
dtypes: object(1000)
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're attempting to show here. In the end I want the columns in the Panel to have the same type as in the original DataFrame (int64 and object). As a work-around I'm just setting them using `p['x']['b'] = p['x']['b'].astype(float)` and it seems to work.